# What is __path__ useful for?

Tags: python, path, module

I had never noticed the `__path__` attribute that gets defined on some of my packages before today.  According to the documentation:

> Packages support one more special
>   attribute, `__path__`. This is
>   initialized to be a list containing
>   the name of the directory holding the
>   package’s `__init__.py` before the code
>   in that file is executed. This
>   variable can be modified; doing so
>   affects future searches for modules
>   and subpackages contained in the
>   package.
>
> While this feature is not often
>   needed, it can be used to extend the
>   set of modules found in a package.

Could somebody explain to me what exactly this means and why I would ever want to use it?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

This is usually used with [pkgutil](http://docs.python.org/library/pkgutil.html) to let a package be laid out across the disk.  E.g., zope.interface and zope.schema are separate distributions (`zope` is a "namespace package").  You might have zope.interface installed in `/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/zope/interface/`, while you are using zope.schema more locally in `/home/me/src/myproject/lib/python2.6/site-packages/zope/schema`.

If you put `pkgutil.extend_path(__path__, __name__)` in `/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/zope/__init__.py` then both zope.interface and zope.schema will be importable because pkgutil will have change `__path__` to `['/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/zope', '/home/me/src/myproject/lib/python2.6/site-packages/zope']`.

`pkg_resources.declare_namespace` (part of Setuptools) is like `pkgutil.extend_path` but is more aware of zips on the path.

Manually changing `__path__` is uncommon and probably not necessary, though it is useful to look at the variable when debugging import problems with namespace packages.

You can also use `__path__` for monkeypatching, e.g., I have monkeypatched distutils at times by creating a file `distutils/__init__.py` that is early on `sys.path`:

```
import os
stdlib_dir = os.path.dirname(os.__file__)
real_distutils_path = os.path.join(stdlib_dir, 'distutils')
__path__.append(real_distutils_path)
execfile(os.path.join(real_distutils_path, '__init__.py'))
# and then apply some monkeypatching here...
```

Comment: I had a feeling that it had something to do with namespace packages, but I had problems piecing together how it worked.  Thanks!

Answer (score 35):

If you change `__path__`, you can force the interpreter to look in a different directory for modules belonging to that package.

This would allow you to, e.g., load different versions of the same module based on runtime conditions. You might do this if you wanted to use different implementations of the same functionality on different platforms.

Comment: django uses this to dynamically load django-admin.py commands at startup. 
 `commands = {name: 'django.core' for name in find_commands(__path__[0])}`

Answer (score 9):

In addition to selecting different versions of a module based on runtime conditions as [Syntactic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2699333/6862601) says, this functionality also would allow you to break up your package into multiple pieces / downloads / installs while maintaining the appearance of a single logical package.

Consider the following.

- I have two packages, `mypkg` and `_mypkg_foo`.
- `_mypkg_foo` contains optional module to `mypkg`, `foo.py`.
- as downloaded and installed, `mypkg` doesn't contain a `foo.py`.

`mypkg`'s `__init__.py` can do something like so:

```
try:
    import _mypkg_foo
    __path__.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(_mypkg_foo.__file__)))
    import mypkg.foo
except ImportError:
    pass
```

If someone has installed the package `_mypkg_foo`, then `mypkg.foo` is available to them. If they haven't, it doesn't exist.

Comment: What is the significance of `import mypkg.foo` here?

Answer (score 6):

A particular situation I've come across is when a package becomes large enough that I want to split parts of it into subdirectories without having to change any code that references it.

For example, I have a package called `views` that was collecting a number of supporting utility functions that were getting muddled with the main top-level purpose of the package.  I was able to move these supporting functions into a subdirectory `utils` and add the following line to the `__init__.py` for the `views` package:

```
__path__.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "utils"))
```

With this change too `views/__init_.py`, I could run the rest of the software with the new file structure without any further changes to the files.

(I tried to do something similar with `import` statements in the `views/__init__.py` file, but the sub-package modules were still not visible through an import of the `view` package - I'm not entirely sure if I'm missing something there;  comments on that welcome!)

(This response based on Python 2.7 installation)