# Is it possible to keep shared library modules in separate directory in python

Tags: android, python, linux

I compiled some python modules (which contains some shared libraries) for android.
since android mounts sdcard with noexec option, I am forced to put whole python package (ie, *.py + *.so files) in /data partition or any ware in phone memory

since phone memory is very limited, I need a way to keep only shared libraries in /data partion and all *.py files in /sdcard for a single python package.

for example, for numpy package i wish I could put

"numpy.core.multiarray.so" in /data/local/lib/python27/

&

whole numpy package tree (excluding shared libraries) in /sdcard/python/

(sys.path contains both '/sdcard/python/' & '/data/local/lib/python27/')

Any one help please....

Comment: sys.path should help you, just append you path to the list - [sys.path](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.path)

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is to add the directory to the `PATH`, using `sys.path`. So for your case, it'd look like

```
import sys.path
sys.path.append(r'/data/local/lib/python27/')
```

Comment: I think I need to calrify my question. my question is 'Does python allow us to put files from a single package to different locations??'

Comment: @harish2704 So long as the package is told where all its files are, I don't see why not. Best to ask someone else who could give you a definitive answer.

Answer (score 1):

Modifying the `__path__` variable in the `__init__` file of the package is the solution. For more detail, see [What is **path** useful for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699287/what-is-path-useful-for)