# python import different subpackages with the same root packge name and different locations

Tags: python

I was wondering if anyone could shed light on this. We have multiple package libraries with the same root package e.g. `a`. I also have package `a.b` located in X and package `a.c` located in Y. Both X and Y are in my `PYTHONPATH` and  When I do:

```
import a.c
import a.b
```

I get an error: `"No module named b"`. After reading around it seems to me that once `a.c` is loaded python writes info about `a` as well, and when I come to do `a.b` because it has information about `a` already it never bothers to look in location X for `a.b` and throws an error that no module named `b` can be found.

Moreover, I found that order with which X and Y are specified in the `PYTHONPATH` seem to affect the importing. For example, when I do

```
PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:X:Y python
>>> import a.b    # works
>>> import a.c    # fails
```

But if I do

```
PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:Y:X python
>>> import a.b    # fails
>>> import a.c    # works
```

Is that correct and if so, how can I work around this? It's convenient to have a common module root name and different sub packages reside in different projects etc. Of course, I am coming from Java point of view where you could do this kind of overlap.

Comment: This happens both in python 2 and 3

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have found related question but lost link to it.

The solution is to include:

```
from pkgutil import extend_path
__path__ = extend_path(__path__, __name__)
```

in the root `__init__.py` in **all** projects. In this case in `a/__init__.py` **BOTH** at location *X* and *Y*. If you have multiple levels of subpackages you still only need to include it once.

[This](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/542192-import-of-subpackages-from-different-physical-loca/) helped me and [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pkgutil.html) for `extend_path`, and info [What is __path__ useful for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699287/what-is-path-useful-for)

Comment: Old topic, but I have found a [better way](https://packaging.python.org/guides/packaging-namespace-packages/#native-namespace-packages) for python3