# How can python import different subpackages from different locations?

Tags: python, python-2.7, mod-wsgi

I have an old system that I’m trying to replicate. It is based on an old Debian Wheezy (7.1) system and uses Apache 2.2.22 and libapache2-mod-wsgi 3.3, in daemon mode, and Python 2.7.3. The WSGI application uses packages from a virtualenv, created with access to the global site-packages modules. It uses two subpackages from the same namespace package, that are installed by the system in different places:

- `repoze.who`, installed in `/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/`
- `repoze.lru`, installed in `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/`

My problem is that it does not work on the replicated system: the application fails to import `repoze.who`. On the other hand, on the original system, it works file and successfully imports both subpackages.

I understand that it’s not supposed to work since, in normal configuration, Python does not expect a package to be split in several places.

I read the [python import different subpackages with the same root packge name and different locations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26058978/python-import-different-subpackages-with-the-same-root-packge-name-and-different) question and its answer. If I modify both `repoze/__init__.py` files as suggested, it works fine on the replicated system.

But I checked both files on the original system, and they are empty.

I added a few `print` instructions in the WSGI application, to investigate the original system. `sys.path` looks fine and similar on both systems, with `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` before `/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7` on both. Surprisingly, the `repoze` package is imported from `/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7` on the original system, while it is imported from `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` on the replicated system. Moreover, `repoze.__path__` contains both locations on the original system, while it only contains `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/repoze` on the replicated system.

Last but not least, if I run the virtualenv’s python interpreter on the original system, it fails to import the `repoze.who` package while it imports `repoze.lru` file, which looks like a normal behaviour. Hence, there must be something special with mod-wsgi or the application.

I guess something “clever” was done to allow the WSGI application to load both packages from different locations, but I have no idea what. Any suggestion is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

`repoze` is using [namespace packages](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/packaging-namespace-packages/).

From [its `setup.py`](https://github.com/repoze/repoze.who/blob/master/setup.py):

```
      namespace_packages=['repoze', 'repoze.who', 'repoze.who.plugins'],
```

- See [PEP 420](https://peps.python.org/pep-0420/) for the modern way to build namespace packages.
- See [pkg_resources](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/packaging-namespace-packages/#pkg-resources-style-namespace-packages) for the old way (the approach I have personal experience with, back in the mid-2000s).
- See the [`pkgutil`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pkgutil.html) approach when you need compatibility with existing code already using that approach.

Comment: Thanks, that’s interesting reading about how things should be done. But it does not really answer my question. I wonder why the WSGI application works fine on my original system, while it fails to import repoze.who on the replicated system or when I run the virtualenv’s python interpreter by hand on the original system…