# SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following directory:

```
myProgram
└── app
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── main.py 
    └── mymodule.py
```

mymodule.py:

```
class myclass(object):

def __init__(self):
    pass

def myfunc(self):
    print("Hello!")
```

main.py:

```
from .mymodule import myclass

print("Test")
testclass = myclass()
testclass.myfunc()
```

But when I run it, then I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Users/Myname/Documents/PycharmProjects/myProgram/app/main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .mymodule import myclass
SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import
```

This works:

```
from mymodule import myclass
```

But I get no auto completion when I type this in and there is a message: "unresolved reference: mymodule" and "unresolved reference: myclass".
And in my other project, which I am working on, I get the error: "ImportError: No module named 'mymodule'.

What can I do?

Comment: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0366/

Comment: I came across the same problem. Apparently running script inside a package is considered as a bad practice, and you cant use relative import in that case. Since your main.py is inside the package app, using relative import will cause error. Use relative import only in modules and run the scripts outside the package.

Comment: Use `python -m package.module` instead of `python package/module.py`.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19190695/7414040) is the answer that solves the problem.

Comment: Got this in PyCharm when I accidentally ran the current file I was editing instead of my `main.py` launcher.

Answer (score 56):

I had the same problem and I solved it by using an absolute import instead of a relative one.

for example in your case, you may write something like this:

```
from app.mymodule import myclass
```

You can see in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references).

> Note that relative imports are based on the name of the current
> module. Since the name of the main module is always "`__main__`",
> modules intended for use as the main module of a Python application
> must always use absolute imports.

Edit: If you encounter this error `ImportError: No module named 'app.app'; 'app' is not a package`, remember to add the `__init__.py` file in your `app` directory so that the interpreter can see it as a package. It is fine if the file is empty.

Comment: If do this I get another error, a `ImportError: No module named 'app.app'; 'app' is not a package`: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/ac0b7b3c36b0a60be6273394d1ddbdfb

Comment: @fiatjaf please can you share the structure of your code with us ?

Comment: Thank you, @Erman. Just did it in a comment on that [gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/ac0b7b3c36b0a60be6273394d1ddbdfb#gistcomment-2216728).

Comment: Have you declare your __init__.py file ? Please make to declare your all your packages inside.

Comment: For more infornation about __init__.py file, check this link. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages

Comment: Good answer! But the quote from the python documentation makes no sense to me. Why should the name `__main__` for the main module necessitate absolute imports for that module?

Comment: @erman But then why relative import won't work in the first place? [The doc you referenced to](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references), in its second paragraph of that section, actually mentions "you can also write relative imports..." and then even provides examples. PS: Currently I encounter same issue, and the package is an open source project owned by someone else, so it is inconvenient to go through that entire project to switch existing relative imports into absolute imports.

Comment: @RayLuo, another way could be to change the variable `__path__` in the `__init__.py` file and add the subdirectories you need. But, note that it could affect the future search of module and submodule. You can check its usage here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699287/what-is-path-useful-for

Answer (score 19):

I usually use this workaround:

```
try:
    from .mymodule import myclass
except Exception: #ImportError
    from mymodule import myclass
```

Which means your IDE should pick up the right code location and the python interpreter will manage to run your code.

Comment: `except Exception` catches *any* exception, which is not what you want.

Comment: But then do I want `SystemError` or `ImportError`?

Comment: You want `ImportError`

Comment: I just wanted to outline that OP, confusingly, has a `SystemError`

Comment: If you want to catch both, catch both (`except SystemError, ImportError`); don't catch all errors.

Answer (score 8):

if you just run the `main.py` under the `app`, just import like

```
from mymodule import myclass
```

if you want to call `main.py` on other folder, use:

```
from .mymodule import myclass
```

---

for example:

```
├── app
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── main.py
│   ├── mymodule.py
├── __init__.py
└── run.py
```

**main.py**

```
from .mymodule import myclass
```

**run.py**

```
from app import main
print(main.myclass)
```

So I think the main question of you is how to call `app.main`.

Comment: Yes, that is the question. How do we do it?

Comment: I think the first part is the opposite of the second part of your answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you go one level up in running the script in the command line of your bash shell, the issue will be resolved. To do this, use `cd ..` command to change the working directory in which your script will be running. The result should look like this:

```
[username@localhost myProgram]$
```

rather than this:

```
[username@localhost app]$
```

Once you are there, instead of running the script in the following format:

```
python3 mymodule.py
```

Change it to this:

```
python3 app/mymodule.py
```

This process can be repeated once again one level up depending on the structure of your Tree diagram. Please also include the compilation command line that is giving you that mentioned error message.