# Python subpackage in arbitrary folder. How to write the __init__.py?

Tags: python, package

If I have this hierarchy

```
A
|- __init__.py
|-B
  |- __init__.py
  |- funcitons.py 
     (which contains def my_function(): pass)
```

and I have package `A` installed, I can do the following

```
from A.B import functions
functions.my_function()
```

or

```
from A.B.functions import my_function
my_function()
```

How to accomplish the same result if B is encapsulated in several subfolders (which are not packages)?

Comment: touching `sys.path` is always wrong. Which python version is this? Python 2? Python 3? Modify `__path__` in the `A/__init__.py`

Comment: One is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699287/what-is-path-useful-for - the other is to use https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420/

Comment: Python 2, but Python 3 compatibility would be useful

Comment: then the former. Naturally compatibility would be useful when writing in a language that has already been given a death sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by Antti Haapala, in Python 2 this is what `__path__` is for. The following `A/__init__.py` did the job.

```
import os
__path__.append( os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'res/path'))
```

see also [What is __path__ useful for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699287/what-is-path-useful-for)