# how to make __main__ a package -OR- script and a package submodule at the same time

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this structure:

```
app.py
sub/
    __init__.py
    lib.py
    utils.py
```

In `app.py`, I want to be able to do sth like this:

```
from sub.lib import some_func
```

In `lib.py`, I want to be able to import `utils.py`.

**And I also want that it's possible to execute `lib.py` as a script directly.** (I.e. `cd sub; python3 lib.py`.)

The problem is, if I start `lib.py` as a script, it will not be a package, and thus, it cannot use relative imports, so sth like `from .utils import some_util_func` would not work. However, if I import `lib.py` as part of the `sub` package, only the relative import will work.

How do I solve this? (In an easy way. E.g. without creating another small wrapper script just to call `lib.py`.)

E.g. if there is a way to mark the `__main__` module as a package, it would solve that. But how? Is this possible? E.g. by defining `__path__` or so?

Comment: I would argue that running a module as a script is the wrong thing to do most of the time. If you something that can run as a script, create a separate script and import `lib`.

Comment: @chepner: I think I have a valid case (it's just a simple demo, which runs `some_func` directly). Maybe just a matter of taste anyway. But I don't really understand why it's wrong to do that (except that I run into the problem described here in the question). Or asked differently: What's the problem with it (and with the current solution I wrote in my own answer)?

Comment: The problem is that modules and scripts have two very different use cases, and the `if __name == "__main__"` hack to support both with the same file only works in simple cases.

Comment: @chepner In what case does it not work? I don't really see what problem would be with this. (Except maybe that this is an uncommon thing to do, at least for now.)

Comment: Well, for starters, relative imports break without explicit `PYTHONPATH` hacking...

Comment: @chepner I don't need any `PYTHONPATH` hacking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, actually, my last comment really worked. If I add this in the beginning of `lib.py`, it seems to work:

```
import os

if __name__ == '__main__':
    __path__ = [os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))]
```

(About `__path__`, see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699287/what-is-path-useful-for).)

**Edit** With newer Python versions (3.9), this does not seem to be enough anymore. See below for an extended version.

---

Also, in [PEP 366](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0366/) it is mentioned:

> When the main module is specified by its filename, then the `__package__` attribute will be set to `None`. To allow relative imports when the module is executed directly, boilerplate similar to the following would be needed before the first relative import statement:

> ```
> if __name__ == "__main__" and __package__ is None:
> ```

```
    __package__ = "expected.package.name"
```

I didn't tried this yet.

---

For Python 3.9, I needed to extend my solution:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Make relative imports work here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54576879/
    __path__ = [os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))]
    __package__ = "YOUR_CUSTOM_PACKAGE_NAME"
    pkg_mod = types.ModuleType(__package__)
    sys.modules[__package__] = pkg_mod
    pkg_mod.__package__ = __package__
    pkg_mod.__file__ = os.path.abspath("__init__.py")
    pkg_mod.__path__ = __path__
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set PYTHONPATH environment variable when starting your program.

Just type from lib directory:

```
PYTHNONPATH="path/to/root/directory" python lib.py
```

Comment: No, that will not work here, because still `__main__` is not a package, so relative imports will not work. And also, I want that I can run the script as-is, without setting some env-var in the right way beforehand.