# How to define the `__path__` attribute for a module in python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

**TL;DR**

I want to create a package (in fact, a package and sub-packages) in python3.

From python3 [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#packages)

> packages are just a special kind of module. Specifically, any module that contains a `__path__` attribute is considered a package.

My question is, where and how do I define the `__path__` attribute?

**My problem**

I have the following directory/file structure in a python3 setup.

```
root_dir
├── migrate
    └── lib
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── database.py
        └── migrate.py
```

How do I turn `migrate` directory into a package, to be able to run

`python -m migrate.lib.migrate`

from inside the `root_dir`. I know that adding an `__init__.py` inside `migrate` directory will suffice to execute the above. But I wish to know understand more about the `__path__` attribute.

Comment: You should never need to set `__path__` yourself.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Does that mean that the only way to turn a directory into a package in python2/3 is to add a `__init__.py` inside it?

Comment: Also, does adding `__init__.py` modify the `__path__` attribute?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699287/what-is-path-useful-for what-is-path-useful-for