# Python Finding all packages inside a package, even when in an egg

Tags: python, import, package, setuptools, egg

Given a Python package, how can I automatically find all its sub-packages?

I used to have a function that would just browse the file system, looking for folders that have an `__init__.py*` file in them, but now I need a method that would work even if the whole package is in an egg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[pkgutil](http://docs.python.org/library/pkgutil.html) could be helpfull.

Also see [this SO question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1707709/list-all-the-modules-that-are-part-of-a-python-package), this is a code example form [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1707709/list-all-the-modules-that-are-part-of-a-python-package).

[kaizer.se](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1707709/list-all-the-modules-that-are-part-of-a-python-package/1707786#1707786)

```
import pkgutil
# this is the package we are inspecting -- for example 'email' from stdlib
import email
package = email
for importer, modname, ispkg in pkgutil.iter_modules(package.__path__):
    print "Found submodule %s (is a package: %s)" % (modname, ispkg)
```

[~unutbu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1707709/list-all-the-modules-that-are-part-of-a-python-package/1708706#1708706)

```
import pkgutil
for importer, modname, ispkg in pkgutil.walk_packages(path=None, onerror=lambda x: None):
    print(modname)
```