# Serial import python

Tags: python, module, serial-port, pyserial

I"m trying to use pyserial.  When I do the following script.

```
import serial
ser= serial.serial("COM5", 9600)
ser.write("Hello worldn")
x = ser.readline()
print(x)
```

Error code:

```
c:\Python27>python com.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "com.py", line 2, in <module>
    ser= serial.serial("COM5", 9600)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'serial'
```

I read a suggestion and changed it to:

```
from serial import serial
ser= serial.serial("COM5", 9600)
ser.write("Hello worldn
x = ser.readline()
print(x)
```

I now get the error

```
c:\Python27>python com.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "com.py", line 1, in <module>
    from serial import serial
ImportError: cannot import name serial
```

I read that this can be from having **ini** in your module, but dont' know anyting about this.

I printed my sys.path and pyserial is in there.

```
['C:\\Users\\Jeff\\Desktop', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\distribute-0.6.4
9-py2.7.egg', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\pyserial-2.7-py2.7.egg', 'C:\\W
indows\\SYSTEM32\\python27.zip', 'C:\\Python27\\DLLs', 'C:\\Python27\\lib', 'C:\
\Python27\\lib\\plat-win', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\lib-tk', 'C:\\Python27', 'C:\\Pyt
hon27\\lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\setuptools-0.6c11
-py2.7.egg-info']
```

Getting kind of annoyed :(...  Thanks for help.

Comment: what is your exact stack trace ?

Comment: The error you are getting means your interpreter cannot locate the serial module. Have you installed it? Are you sure you have proper permissions to use it?

Comment: I installed the module using distribute easy-install.  the folder is under python27/lib-site-packages/pyserial-2.7-py2.7.egg/serial.   also added the stack traces.

Comment: Did you happen to call one of *your* programs `serial.py`?  At the start of your code, add `import serial` and `print(serial.__file__)` as the first two lines.

Comment: I did name it serial.py initially, but changed it.  Here is the output of the print.
c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyserial-2.7-py2.7.egg\serial\__init__.pyc

Comment: I'll second that. DONT NAME YOUR FILE SERIAL.PY.  sorry for all caps but I've been burned by this twice in two years, and I missed this comment in this file both times.  Thanks :)

Comment: I hava had similar problems with my python 3.6.5 and I needed to uninstall "serial" with pip and then install "pyserial" with pip.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It should be:

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial("COM5", 9600)
```

Note the capital 'S' in serial.Serial

Comment: That appears to be it!  At least the error went away, I'll have to wait until I"m home to be sure it's actually talking to the port.  Dang capitalization and indentation get me every time :).  Thanks

Comment: import serial ; help(serial)