# import serial in python 2.7 giving an error

Tags: python

[image]

import serial runs successfully but while executing command (from serial import Serial), giving the following error

Comment: Serial? Are you sure it's not `pyserial`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Serial import python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19728535/serial-import-python)

Comment: @PirateX No, that is not the problem here