# glpk.LPX backward compatiblity?

Tags: python, matlab, glpk

Newer versions of `glpk` do not have the `LPX` api, which is required by older packages. 
How can I use an older package (like [COBRA](http://opencobra.sourceforge.net/openCOBRA/Welcome.html)) with the newer versions of `glpk`?

Note that `COBRA` is available for MATLAB and Python. Both require `glpk` and the `LPX` api, and I would like to use both.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/21431403/855050

Comment: In the end I had to install an older version of glpk.

Answer (score 2):

Ideally you should switch to a version that uses the new API. It has been around for years. If that is no option, then the following entry in the ChangeLog to V4.53 points in the right direction

```
    * examples/oldapi/lpx.h, examples/oldapi/lpx.c
    A set of routines that simulate the old GLPK API (as defined
    in 4.48) were added. Thanks to Jan Engelhardt <jengelh@inai.de>
    for suggestion.
```

In the directory `examples/oldapi` of the source release you find everything you need.  Excerpt from README:

```
The program module in this subdirectory contains an implementation of
the old GLPK API as it was defined in GLPK 4.48.

To compile an existing project using the old GLPK API you need to add
to the project two files lpx.h and lpx.c.
```

Comment: Note that if you have GLPK 4.58+, also comment out the `lpx_main` definition in `lpx.c`, as it calls the `glp_main` function which was removed in GLPK 4.58.