# Error import nmap into python

Tags: python, nmap

I installed nmap module for python. 
While i was importing nmap,it received error. This error is attribute error.

Command line:

```
root@harun:~/Desktop# python nmap.py

Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "nmap.py", line 2, in <module>
    import nmap
   File "/root/Desktop/nmap.py", line 3, in <module>
    nm = nmap.PortScanner()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'PortScanner'
```

this code is:

```
!/usr/bin/env python

import nmap
nm = nmap.PortScanner()
```

I changed code this:

```
!/usr/bin/env python

from nmap import nmap
nm = nmap.PortScanner()
```

But it received same error.

one more changed:

```
!/usr/bin/env python
 import nmap
 directory=dir(nmap)
 print directory
```

this received:

```
 root@harun:~/Desktop# python nmap.py
 ['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', 'nmap']
 ['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', 'directory', 'nmap']
```

But normally:

```
 root@harun:~# python
 >>> dir(nmap)

['PortScanner', 'PortScannerAsync', 'PortScannerError', 'PortScannerHostDict', 'PortScannerYield', 'Process', '__author__', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__last_modification__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__version__', 'collections', 'convert_nmap_output_to_encoding', 'csv', 'io', 'nmap', 'os', 're', 'shlex', 'string', 'subprocess', 'sys', 'types', 'xml']
```

Could you tell me how I do ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Serial'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11403932/python-attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-serial)

Comment: i fix error after remove any space in my project name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the link in the comment ('module' object has no attribute 'Serial') –is relevant. So instead of `import nmap`, try `from nmap import PortScanner` and then `nm = PortScanner`

The fact that you are calling your program `nmap.py` may in the future cause conflicts, so you may want to rename that.

Comment: I agree. But at first while i was sharing, moderator suggested. So i changed it. I changed name and instead of import nmap , wrote from nmap import nmap. But it doesn't work.

Comment: Did you try renaming the file too?

Comment: Make sure you get rid of the old nmap.pyc or cache file if that's there. If that doesn't do it break out a debugger. I have a good one called trepan2.  You should be able to step into the import statement.

Answer (score -1):

You should uninastall all pip after that install zenmap for windows and pip install comand after you have to restart your pc

Comment: This wont fix the issue as it's the way in which it is imported that is the issue, not a missing module.