# Python Module issues

Tags: python, module

Im pretty new to python, and have been having a rough time learning it. I have a main file

```
import Tests
from Tests import CashAMDSale

CashAMDSale.AMDSale()
```

and CashAMDSale

```
import pyodbc
import DataFunctions
import automa
from DataFunctions import *
from automa.api import *

def AMDSale():
    AMDInstance = DataFunctions.GetValidAMD()
```

And here is GetValidAMD

```
import pyodbc

def ValidAMD(GetValidAMD):
     (short method talking to a database)
```

My error comes up on the line that has `AMDInstance = DataFunctions.GetValidAMD()`

I get the error `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'GetValidAMD'`

I have looked and looked for an answer, and nothing has worked. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the source code of the ``DataFunctions`` module?

Comment: DataFunctions is the folder i have GetValidAMD in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DataFunctions` is a folder, which means it is a package and must contain an `__init__.py` file for python to recognise it as such.

when you import * from a package, you do not automatically import all it's modules. This is documented in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package)

so for your code to work, you either need to explicitly import the modules you need:

```
import DataFunctions.GetValidAMD
```

or you need to add the following to the `__init__.py` of `DataFunctions`:

```
__all__ = ["GetValidAMD"]
```

then you can `import *` from the package and everything listen in `__all__` will be imported

Answer (score 1):

When you create the file `foo.py`, you create a python module. When you do `import foo`, Python evaluates that file and places any variables, functions and classes it defines into a module object, which it assigns to the name `foo`.

```
# foo.py
x = 1
def foo():
    print 'foo'
```

```
>>> import foo
>>> type(foo)
<type 'module'>
>>> foo.x
1
>>> foo.foo()
foo
```

When you create the directory `bar` with an `__init__.py` file, you create a python package. When you do `import bar`, Python evaluates the `__init__.py` file and places any variables, functions and classes it defines into a module object, which it assigns to the name `bar`.

```
# bar/__init__.py
y = 2
def bar():
    print 'bar'
```

```
>>> import bar
>>> type(bar)
<type 'module'>
>>> bar.y
2
>>> bar.bar()
bar
```

When you create python *modules* inside a python *package* (that is, files ending with `.py` inside directory containing `__init__.py`), you must import these modules via this package:

```
>>> # place foo.py in bar/
>>> import foo
Traceback (most recent call last):
    ...
ImportError: No module named foo
>>> import bar.foo
>>> bar.foo.x
1
>>> bar.foo.foo()
foo
```

Now, assuming your project structure is:

```
main.py
DataFunctions/
    __init__.py
    CashAMDSale.py
        def AMDSale(): ...
    GetValidAMD.py
        def ValidAMD(GetValidAMD): ...
```

your `main` script can `import DataFunctions.CashAMDSale` and use `DataFunctions.CashAMDSale.AMDSale()`, and `import DataFunctions.GetValidAMD` and use `DataFunctions.GetValidAMD.ValidAMD()`.

Comment: I should have clarified my folder structure, sorry! 
Its

`main.py
      DataFunctions/
           __init__.py
           GetValidAMD.py
      Tests/
           __init__.py
           CashAMDSale.py`

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11403932/python-attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-serial).

It's the same problem. You are importing `DataFunctions` which is a module. I expct there to be a class called DataFunctions in that module which needs to be imported with

```
from DataFunctions import DataFunctions
...
AMDInstance = DataFunctions.GetValidAMD()
```