# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'vtkvmtkVesselEnhancingDiffusion3DImageFilter'

Tags: python, module, attributes, vtk

I get the following error when I try to run the script for the VEDm filter in vmtk:

```
[location] line 149, in ApplyVEDManniesing
vesselness = vtkvmtk.vtkvmtkVesselEnhancingDiffusion3DImageFilter()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'vtkvmtkVesselEnhancingDiffusion3DImageFilter'
```

I tried to run the code in my Python 3.6 environment, instead of 2.7 where I currently work in. But it gave the same error.

The other filters (Sato, Frangi, VED) were completed successfully and are represented in the same python-file `vmtkimagevesselenhancement.py`.

Can someone help me to find the problem?

**Edit**: this is what the beginning of the code looks like:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import #NEEDS TO STAY AS TOP LEVEL MODULE FOR Py2-3 COMPATIBILITY
import vtk
import sys

import pypes
import vtkvmtk
```

The filename where the line 149 doesn't work is `vmtkimagevesselenhancement`.py and is imported with the vmtk download.

Comment: Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11403932/python-attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-serial).

Comment: I deleted the files `pypes.pyc` and `vmtk.pyc`, because I couldn't import the module vmtk with it. I use Pycharm and when I typed `from vmtk import p` it came up with no suggestions. Same for `import vtkvmtk`. Maybe I'm missing something, I'm very new to coding.