# Raspberry Pi Arduino Serial with Python

Tags: python, arduino, raspberry-pi

I'm aware of this being the same question as in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11403932/python-attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-serial). However, I tried the named solutions (yes, all of them [I think]) and it still gives the same error message.

I tried to establish a serial connection between my Raspberry and Arduino (Mega 2560). After installing the serial package (`pip install serial`, `sudo apt-get install python-serial`), my script file being called "arduino.py", the code being:

```
import serial

MySer = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 9600)
```

I still get the same error message (AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Serial').

Now did I do something inherently wrong? Do I have to set some permissions or... I'm a little lost here. ^^

Thanks in advance,

Tim

Comment: `pip uninstall serial` and `pip install pyserial` ? see: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/serial/0.0.24 vs https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyserial

Answer (score 0):

Thanks dda - that was the right direction.

I uninstalled serial and installed pyserial, now it works phenomenally (at least from what I gather in the few minutes between coffee and work).

Thank you so much!

Best of wishes,

Tim