# How to solve AttributeError: module 'serial' has no attribute 'Serial' in pyserial?

Tags: python, pyserial

I have a Windows 10 with Python 3.7.4 and I use Jupyter Notebook. I'm trying to use pySerial to connect to my Arduino by Serial attribute. I tried installing pySerial simply by pip install pyserial and eventually I tried conda install -c conda-forge pyserial too, but when I try to run my code:

```
 import serial
 ser = serial.Serial('COM4', 9600)
```

I get an error message like:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-413d0d9dabe7> in <module>
      2 import serial
      3 import time
----> 4 ser = serial.Serial('COM4', 9600)
      5 
      6 # Your Account Sid and Auth Token from twilio.com/console

AttributeError: module 'serial' has no attribute 'Serial'
```

Also, I tried

```
import serial
serial.__file__
```

And I got 'C:\Users\lippe\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\serial\__init__.py' as output.

I also tried dir(serial) and I can't see the Serial attribute in the output, so I think it's basically not installed and I don't know why.
I tried digging the internet but I still can't find a solution.

Comment: I've looked through the docs but, as unlikely as it is to give this error; did you call your script `serial.py`? If so, you need to rename it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11404052/669576

Comment: No I didn't call my script serial.py. I'm not supposed to be using serial instead of pyserial either, but everything I read about this error says I'm using the wrong package. I don't understand why as I uninstalled serial several times. I just tried to uninstall it again and I got "Skipping serial as it is not installed". I also tried to run the script in a friend's pc and I got the same errors... Even if serial wasn't installed either.

Comment: As always I think the problem is somehow Windows but I can't use Linux right now. I'll try to run my script in a Linux later and I'll let you know.

Comment: I solved it by changing my IDE to pyCharm. I still don't know why it didn't work with Anaconda but at least now I have a working script. Thank you guys :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're importing the right serial. After installing pyserial with pip, you can use the `__file__` attribute to check that it's the one I expect like so:

```
>>> import serial
>>> serial.__file__
'/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/serial/__init__.py'
```

Other answers suggest it might work to import the class directly with

```
from serial import Serial
```

But I'm not sure why this would matter if you're importing the latest published on pypi.