# Python - module 'serial' has no attribute 'Serial'

Tags: python, serial-port, pyserial

I wrote a small program in order to learn how to interface with my arduino. 
Actually, i got it here:
https://github.com/WaveShapePlay/ArduinoPySerial_LearningSeries/blob/master/Part2_AddingUserInput/ArduinoSerialCom.py

This is the code:

```
import serial

ser = serial.Serial('COM3', baudrate = 9600, timeout = 1)

def getValues():

    ser.write(b'g')
    arduinoData = ser.readline().decode('ascii')
    return arduinoData


while(1):

    userInput = input('Get data point?')

    if userInput == 'y':
        print(getValues())
```

I changed the COM port to be the one my arduino is using.
Unfortuantely i get this error:

```
ser = serial.Serial('COM14', baudrate = 9600, timeout
AttributeError: module 'serial' has no attribute 'Serial'
```

Many people have gad this program, so i did a lot of reading online in order to mitigate it.

I tried:
*`from serial import Serial` (instead of `import serial`)
* `pip uninstall serial` and then `pip install pyserial`. It succefully uninstalled serial but pyserial was already installed. Still it didn't work.

I am out of ideas... Any help pelase?

Comment: Do you have a file called "serial.py" in your local directory? After import and before the error, add `print(serial.__file__)` to see if its the right file.

Comment: I do not have a file like that in my directory. I tried your code anyway and i got "None".

Comment: Have you looked at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11403932/python-attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-serial

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I am having the same problem on `2020-02-13 Buster Lite`

Comment: Yes but i will post tomorrow because i have to sleep sorry

Comment: I posted the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code that worked for me

```
import serial

ser = serial.Serial('COM14', baudrate = 9600, timeout = 1)


def getValues():

    ser.write(b'rf')
    arduinoData = ser.readline().decode('ascii')
    return arduinoData


while(1):

    userInput = input('Get data point?')

    if userInput == 'y':
        print(getValues())
```