# Python 3 AttributeError: module 'serial' has no attribute 'Serial'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyserial

I've seen a lot of questions on here that have this same issue, but I haven't found a solution that works yet. I'm trying to run this [face tracking program](https://create.arduino.cc/projecthub/WolfxPac/face-tracking-using-arduino-b35b6b), but I can't get it to work. I know that the program says that it's written for python 2.7, but as far as I know there isn't that much of a difference in the language structure, right? I have a pretty firm understanding of the basics of python, but I'm still going through school.

The issue is in the title, I downloaded pyserial, open-cv and numpy through the terminal on mac into /3.8/bin. However, when I try to run the code below, it throws an AttributeError like I don't have serial installed. Am I missing something, or misreading something? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Input:

```
   #import all the required modules
    import numpy as np
    import serial
    import time
    import sys
    import cv2
    arduino = serial.Serial('/dev/cu.usbmodem14201', 9600)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/daPWNDAZ/Desktop/Arduino/Codes/FaceTracking/face.py", line 7, in <module>
    arduino = serial.Serial('/dev/cu.usbmodem14201', 9600)
AttributeError: module 'serial' has no attribute 'Serial'
```

Comment: An error "like I don't have serial installed" would be an `ImportError`.  This looks more like you have a `serial.py` file somewhere, that is being imported instead of the actual module.  Do `import serial; print(serial.__file__)` to see where it is.

Comment: or [Python AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Serial'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11403932)

Comment: I looked in my directory and couldn't find any file named 'serial.py'. Jason's code returned a file named '__init__.py'. I have a folder named "serial' in my directory, but that was installed when I ran pip.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you have a python script in your directory named "serial". Rename that file and you should be good

Comment: I looked around in my directory and could only find a folder named 'serial'. I did find a 'serialcli.py' file, but again, not 'serial'.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer!
I couldn't find any files named "serial", so I dug around a bit more in the answers gre_gor gave. It got fixed by uninstalling pyserial from the command line and reinstalling it (as suggested in the second link), which I could have sworn I had already done. I'm not getting any errors anymore, thank you all!