# Importing Modules from Python Package without specifying their names

Tags: python, import, module, package

I am trying to import modules in Python dynamically.
That means - I have a Python package with modules inside.
Without specifying the modules names, I want to keep a dictionary of each module's name to the pointer to this module.

I tried to use the suggestion from [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1707709/list-all-the-modules-that-are-part-of-a-python-package)

My directory is:

```
foo/
    __init__.py
    bar1.py
    bar2.py
```

the script I use is:

```
import pkgutil
import foo

for importer, name, ispkg in pkgutil.iter_modules(foo.__path__, foo.__name__ + "."):
    print "Found submodule %s (is a package: %s)" % (name, ispkg)
    module = __import__(name)
    print "Imported", module
```

The output I get for the first iteration is:

```
Found submodule foo.bar1 (is a package: False)
Imported <module 'foo' from '/path/to/foo/__init__.pyc'>
```

So instead of getting my bar1 module using this, I get the foo package with the import.

How can I get the bar1 and bar2 modules?

Other methods are welcome if the use of pkgutil is not right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [**import** documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#__import__):

> When the *name* variable is of the form `package.module`, normally, the top-level package (the name up till the first dot) is returned, *not* the module named by *name*. However, when a non-empty *fromlist* argument is given, the module named by *name* is returned.

Also, importing a package seems to be enough in order to use a submodule of that:

```
anthony@claudia:~$ python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Jan  2 2013, 13:56:14) 
[GCC 4.7.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> os.path.join('one', 'two')
'one/two'
>>>
```

And, vice-versa, importing a submodule implicitly imports its parent module:

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Jan  2 2013, 13:56:14) 
[GCC 4.7.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os.path
>>> os.tmpfile()
<open file '<tmpfile>', mode 'w+b' at 0x7f565495d4b0>
>>>
```

Therefore maybe simply importing `foo` is enough for you.

The formal details of importing are described at length in the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#import).