# List submodules of a python module

Tags: python, module

How to get the name/list of all submodules of an already imported Python module? (Not the external imported module/packages, just that one in the same folder as module sub-folder).

I am using

```
import inspect
print([o[0] for o in inspect.getmembers(module_imported) if inspect.ismodule(o[1])])
```

but this print also the system modules imported and files in the main module folder.

Comment: Importing a package does not automatically import the submodules

Comment: This is a fairly trivial question (don't see why *Google* wouldn't yield lots of hits). Please post what you've tried so far, and where did you encounter problems. Check [\[SO\]: How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) or [\[SO\]: mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for more asking related details.

Comment: I am using `import inspect
print([o[0] for o in inspect.getmembers(module_imported) if inspect.ismodule(o[1])])`, but this print also the system modules imported and files in the main module folder.

Comment: Ok, please add that info into the question as it might be valuable.

Comment: Yes @wim, I know that submodules are not automatically imported. But, importing a module that (not important here) import submodule, how to difference the local module of the Python packages? The code that I posted not get this difference.

Comment: I just make a function which can be easily used, check https://stackoverflow.com/a/77154867/7341454

Answer (score 30):

Use `pkgutil`, though it doesn't always work with pyinstaller.

```
pkgutil.iter_modules(imported_module.__path__)
```

Comment: This is the way.

Comment: this is the most logical way to do this without too many extra steps.

Comment: This is the way!

Answer (score 12):

How about using `dir` on the module to get all the submodules or attributes listed ?

```
In [1]: import requests

In [2]: dir(requests)
Out[2]:
['ConnectTimeout',
 'ConnectionError',
 'DependencyWarning',
 'FileModeWarning',
 'HTTPError',
 'NullHandler',
 'PreparedRequest',
 'ReadTimeout',
 'Request',
 'RequestException',
 'Response',
 'Session',
 'Timeout',
 'TooManyRedirects',
 'URLRequired',
 '__author__',
 '__build__',
 '__builtins__',
 '__cached__',
 '__copyright__',
 '__doc__',
 '__file__',
 '__license__',
 '__loader__',
 '__name__',
 '__package__',
 '__path__',
 '__spec__',
 '__title__',
 '__version__',
 'adapters',
 'api',
 'auth',
 'certs',
 'codes',
 'compat',
 'cookies',
 'delete',
 'exceptions',
 'get',
 'head',
 'hooks',
 'logging',
 'models',
 'options',
 'packages',
 'patch',
 'post',
 'put',
 'request',
 'session',
 'sessions',
 'status_codes',
 'structures',
 'utils',
 'warnings']
```

Comment: `dir()` “attempts to produce the most relevant, rather than complete, information”. Personally, I have received inconsistent return values. Source: docs.python.org/library/functions.html#dir

Answer (score 11):

You can use the `predicate` argument of the `getmembers` method. It acts similarly to a filter.
In this case, it would be:

```
inspect.getmembers(module_imported, inspect.ismodule)
```

Answer (score 8):

Here's a copy-pasteable version of [GraphicalDot's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58684066/2745495).

Just change `my_imported_module` to the module you want to inspect.

```
from pkgutil import iter_modules

def list_submodules(module):
    for submodule in iter_modules(module.__path__):
        print(submodule.name)

list_submodules(my_imported_module)
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
import some_module
for i in dir(some_module):
    print(i)
```

Comment: It's almost the same as [this answer that mention `dir`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48000917/2745495).