# Using "from ... import" to import a function directly from a submodule

Tags: python, import, nested

I am trying to understand the syntax logic of Python all about imports. Take for example the function `scipy.signal.ricker`. The function should not matter.

To use this function of Python (without any imports at all) I have to

```
import scipy
```

and then I can use it via

```
scipy.signal.ricker(...)
```

Alternatively I can

```
from scipy import signal
```

and use it via

```
signal.ricker(...)
```

Is there any option to import `ricker` directly so that I just had to write `ricker(...)` and how would I import something else if it would be nested one, two or 10 levels further?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
from scipy.signal import ricker
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `.` operator to search the contents of a module/submodule.

In your case

```py
from scipy.signal import ricker
```

And then simply use it by `ricker(...)`

For more information: [What does a . in an import statement in Python mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7279810/what-does-a-in-an-import-statement-in-python-mean)

Comment: Thanks a lot. For the first option there is displayed an error:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scipy.signal.ricker'

Your explanation arises another question. What do you mean with "search" for the contents of a module/submodule? Will there be the entire (sub)module content listed?

Comment: Yeah removed it. That works only for local packages.

Comment: What do you mean by entire submodule content listed?

Comment: You wrote: "search the contents..."
I have wondered if there will be displayed a list with the content of for example scipy.

Comment: Some IDEs can reference stubs and figure this out. For a pragmatic implementation see https://stackoverflow.com/a/65193885/4861361