# Discord.py Button, Select, View error import

Tags: python, import, discord.py

I want to create a command that generates the select menu but it generates an import error

```
import discord
import datetime
from discord.ui import Select, View
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '.', help_command=None)

@client.command()
async def hello(ctx):
    select = Select(options=[
        discord.SelectOption(label="Hello", emoji= "✌️", description="Hello")
        discord.SelectOption(label="Hello1", emoji= "", description="Hello2")
        ])
    view = View()
    view.add_item(select)
    await ctx.send("Select", view= view)
```

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\bicco\Desktop\Coding\leiaraiel_bot\main.py", line 4, in <module>
    from discord.ui import Select, View
ImportError: cannot import name 'Select' from 'discord.ui' (unknown location)
```

Comment: I don't see `discord.ui` as part of the `discord` module. Could you be specific about which module you're working with? Here's a guide on checking submodules: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48000761/list-submodules-of-a-python-module

Comment: discord.ui is a part of discord.py 2.0. It is likely you are using version 1.7.3

Answer (score 1):

- Update to discord 2.0 using:

```py
pip install discord==2.0
```

If you are using replit to host your code it will show you an error as replit is still not compatible with discord 2.0. Instead, you can go to the shell terminal of replit and do the following:

```py
pip uninstall discord.py # or pip uninstall discord
```

- Wait for some time until replit asks for confirmation and type `y` to confirm the removal.
- Then install it like this:

```py
pip install git+https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py
```

[image: PREVIEW]

Hope it helps.