# How to know what is the importer of a module in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

How can I know the importing node path of a module?

For example, if I do

```
import xxx.xxx
```

Then somehow module `yyy` gets imported.

How can I know the path of the imports of `yyy`? something like

`xxx.xxx -> zzz -> aaa -> yyy`

Comment: Maybe you can use listing multiple times: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1707709/list-all-the-modules-that-are-part-of-a-python-package

Comment: No, that is different question. that question is talking about how to find modules starting from a root. My question is the other way around, `how to find the path to root from a leaf`

Comment: Oh, sorry about that.

Comment: You want to know the import chain to a leaf with code that is located in your leaf?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you start Python with the `-vv` flag then you will see verbose logs, including everything it tries to import.

Comment: A single `-v` should suffice to see imports

Answer (score 0):

Just to know the path using python just use

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

check all the modules available in site-packages only if you want to explore libraries manually