# How to load all modules from a given directory and run a specific function from each

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'd like to dynamically load all modules placed into a given directory (`modules`) and run a specific method in each of them (`.main()`).

I ran across the following question: [How to load all modules in a folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057431/how-to-load-all-modules-in-a-folder)

and ended up with the following code:
my `main.py`

```
import modules

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for module in modules.__all__:
        module.main()
```

The `__init__.py` in the `modules` folder look like this:

```py
from os.path import dirname, basename, isfile, join
import glob

modules = glob.glob(join(dirname(__file__), "*.py"))
__all__ = [ basename(f)[:-3] for f in modules if isfile(f) and not f.endswith('__init__.py')]
```

However, I get the below error:

```
'str' object has no attribute 'main'
```

I believe this is some kind of newbie question, but I cannot figure out how to do things.

Comment: This answer is relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1707709/list-all-the-modules-that-are-part-of-a-python-package. You should be able to add your .main() to the end of the top answer

Comment: You missed some very important point that, sadly, is a bist lost in a long list of comments: "Add `from . import *` after setting `__all__` if you want submodules to be available"

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I'm not quite sure I understand what you mean by adding 'from . import *`
If I add it to the `__init__.py` file, the error about the module not being found remains.

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the module first

```
import modules
import importlib

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for module in modules.__all__:
        importlib.import_module(module).main()
```

Comment: The use of `__import__` should be reserved for when you _really_ need it - the recommanded solution is to use `importlib.import_module()`

Comment: surely this only works if the modules directory is on the path...?

Comment: Thanks, the main point i was trying to express was that the OP was simply passing the string rather than importing the module itself. Ive edited my answer to reflect the recommended solution.

Comment: @tomgalpin that's better but still not ok. The imports should happen in `modules/__init__.py`, not in the calling code (`modules.__all__` should still be a list of strings, but those string should match the available module's attributes so if you have `modules.__all__ = ["foo"]` then `module.foo` should  be valid (IOW `module` should have an attribute named "foo").

Comment: Tweaking the code from @tomgalpin, I ended up with:
`importlib.import_module('modules.'+module)` which is not really elegant but works